# In case the example data structure is considered to be a Linked List, how does one write a function which does print out all of its members?

Tags: javascript, linked-list, iteration

I just started learning Linked List for a technical interview, so this question might seem a little weird.

I was reading an introduction article about Linked List from freecodecamp, and this is what the article

In JavaScript, a linked list looks like this:

```js
const list = {
    head: {
        value: 6
        next: {
            value: 10                                             
            next: {
                value: 12
                next: {
                    value: 3
                    next: null 
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
};
```

My question is, is this a real Linked List? Say I get a question "Print out all the elements in the following linked list, and implement a Linked List yourself." Can I just use the above code? I do know how to use classes to implement a linked list, but I am just wondering if the above code counts as a linked List.

I am asking this question because I only know how to solve the array algorithm question so far.
Say I want to print out all the elements in the array. I will need three steps.

1. Create an array. // Nums = [1,2,3];
2. write a function to print it out. // function printNums(Nums){ for (...){console.log(Nums[i]}}
3. call the function. // printNums(Nums);

### So now, I want to do a Linked List version of this. How should I do it?

New Update:

So this is my LinkedList version of printing out all the elements. As a comment mentioned, what I did in the code is in fact a linked list, but it's not called implementation. But what if I just want to test my function? Does the following code make sense to you guys?

[image]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223382/discussion-on-question-by-fin-in-case-the-example-data-structure-is-considered-t).

Answer (score 1):

> My question is, is this a real Linked List?

Yes, it is. You have a collection of data elements, where each data element points to the next.

> Say I get a question "Print out all the elements in the following linked list, and implement a Linked List yourself." Can I just use the above code?

When asked to print a specific linked list, we should assume that it is made clear what the exact interface is of that linked list (e.g. nodes are linked via a property called `next`, and their values are accessed via a property called `value`). In case of the example list, that is clear. So yes, you could use the piece of code you provided.

The question to implement a Linked List yourself, is a different one. Although it *could* be understood to *define one particular list*, that is not how most would interpret that question. It is more likely that this means you should implement a linked list *interface*: i.e. write code that not only provides easy ways to construct *any* linked list, but also for using it (find a value, insert a node, delete a node, move a node, ...)

> I am just wondering if the above code counts as a linked List.

Yes, the object literal you provided is (one particular instance of) a linked list.

> Say I want to print out all the elements in the array. I will need three steps.
>
> ```
>     Create an array. // Nums = [1,2,3];
> ```

Here you make use of a feature of the JavaScript language. Implicitly a constructor is behind this: `new Array(1, 2, 3)`. This constructor is provided as part of the core language. You also get access to methods like `push`, `pop`, `indexOf`, `slice`, `splice`, ...etc. All out of the box.

The difference with linked lists is that core JavaScript does not offer an implementation for it. You have to throw your own. Sure, you can use an object literal to create one linked list, but it is quite a verbose way (imagine a list with 100 numbers), and error prone (what if you misspelled `next` somewhere half way?)

> So now, I want to do a Linked List version of this. How should I do it?

If the purpose is only to print the content of a linked list, and nothing else, you can do it like you did. But to get something that offers an interface like you get out of the box for arrays, you would write a class with some useful methods, so you could write:

```
let myList = LinkedList.from(6, 10, 12, 3);
console.log(...myList.values()); // outputs 6 10 12 3
```

> But what if I just want to test my function? Does the following code make sense to you guys?

Yes, that is fine. If you know that your print function will get either `null` or an object that has `value` and `next` properties, where the `next` property can be `null` or another such object, ... then it is fine. In other words: you need to know the *interface*.

Comment: Thank your for your long reply! I understand it now. At first I was just curious how I can test my function like I did for array. It never crossed my mind that easily creating an array is part of the language feature, and creating an array is also using constructor behind the scene.

Answer (score 0):

```
var l = head;
while (l != null) {
    console.log(l.value);
    l = l.next;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it's not really what I am asking. Would you mind take a look at the question description ?

Comment: @Fin, you asked "So now, I want to do a Linked List version of this. How should I do it?", which I provided. All you need to do is put it in the body of a function.

Comment: What I was asking is how do I know if the function is correct. To do so, I need to create a linked list first. So the first block of the code in the question is my quick way to create a linked list. I want to know if the WAY is correct.  (The cap is for emphasizing, sorry if that makes you uncomfortable).
It's more of a general question, rather than asking 'how to print out all the elements in the list'.

Answer (score 0):

Trick is to use while loop until next element is null.

```
let prev: LinkedListElement<T> | null = this._start;
let finalEl: LinkedListElement<T> = prev;
let counter = 0;
while (prev !== null) {
    const retVal = callback(prev, counter);
    if (!retVal) {
    break;
    }
    finalEl = prev;
    prev = prev.next;
    counter++;
}
```

Let me know if this works.
Also look at this LinkedList class I have created, `traverse` function is matching the requirement you have.
[Class GitHub](https://github.com/dsinjs/linked-list)
[NPM package - @dsinjs/linked-list](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@dsinjs/linked-list)
[Complete documentation](https://dsinjs.github.io/linked-list/#traverse)